# Apache2 authentication against ldap fails with "user not found"

Tags: ldap, debian, apache2.4

i installed slapd (2.4.40+dfsg-1+deb8u2) recently, and i' m trying to get apache2 (2.4.10-10+deb8u7) authenticated through ldap. The system itself is debian (8.6).

Ldap should run on localhost on the default port, and using phpldapadmin the DN ( **cn=admin,dc=1000,dc=hu** ) seems to be ok. For apache2 authenticaion i use .htaccess file, and basic authentication (htpasswd file) works also fine.

My configucation is:

```
AuthName "Add your login message here."
AuthType Basic
AuthBasicProvider ldap
AuthLDAPURL "ldap://localhost:389/dc=1000,dc=hu?sAMAccountName?sub?(objectClass=*)"
AuthLDAPBindDN "cn=admin,dc=1000,dc=hu"
AuthLDAPBindPassword ******
require ldap-user testtest test ttest
```

.

Whatever i do, i got the "user not found" error in apache2 logs:

```
==> /var/log/apache2/error.log <==
[Sat Jan 21 12:54:29.272676 2017] [auth_basic:error] [pid 27767] [client 127.0.0.1:52852] AH01618: user ttest not found: /t1/

==> /var/log/apache2/access.log <==
127.0.0.1 - ttest [21/Jan/2017:12:54:29 +0100] "GET /t1/ HTTP/1.1" 401 738 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0"

==> /var/log/apache2/error.log <==
[Sat Jan 21 12:54:44.388323 2017] [auth_basic:error] [pid 27766] [client 127.0.0.1:52854] AH01618: user test not found: /t1/

==> /var/log/apache2/access.log <==
127.0.0.1 - test [21/Jan/2017:12:54:44 +0100] "GET /t1/ HTTP/1.1" 401 738 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0"

==> /var/log/apache2/error.log <==
[Sat Jan 21 12:54:49.460321 2017] [auth_basic:error] [pid 27770] [client 127.0.0.1:52856] AH01618: user testtest not found: /t1/

==> /var/log/apache2/access.log <==
127.0.0.1 - testtest [21/Jan/2017:12:54:49 +0100] "GET /t1/ HTTP/1.1" 401 738 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0"
```

ttest, test and testtest are username, sn, cn in my system.

Password for AuthLDAPBindPassword is triple checked, also for the user.

Where do i make the mistake? Does the AuthLDAPURL have the right value in this scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, in the above example the AuthLDAPURL was wrong for the described setup. It should be only:

```
AuthLDAPURL ldap://localhost/dc=256,dc=hu?cn?sub
```

.

Comment: I wanted, but the site said i need to wait 2 days to accept my own answer (still 32 to go).

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error and it was related to using the default attribute 'uid' with Active Directory, rather than specifying sAMAccountName.

```
AuthLDAPURL ldap://192.168.1.1:389/dc=domain,dc=local?sAMAccountName
```

Answer (score 0):

seem ***AuthLDAPURL*** question

I change:

- ldap://localhost:389/dc=1000,dc=hu?sAMAccountName?sub?(objectClass=*)
- ldap://localhost:389/dc=1000,dc=hu?name

[refer to](https://discourse.osc.edu/t/ldap-authentication-issues-user-not-found/752/13)